# What value should be used for a TrailingStop $ for a PUT Option in eTrade trading platform?

Tags: options, put-options

I have a **PUT contract** for a XYZ stock with a strike price of **$160**. I'm speculating that the stock price of XYZ can go down in the next few weeks. I would like to set up a **TrailingStop** order for a $ amount of **$5**. I'm assuming when the stock drops by $5, move the **stop limit** point. Is it possible to do that for a **PUT**? Should that be a negative or positive value?

I'm using **eTrade** platform and the screen looks like below. I tried to put **2** in the **Stop Value $** field and it shows the estimated proceeds is $194.3. I originally paid $402 for a contract.

[image]

Comment: Contact customer support.  That's what they're there for :->)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is to sell the option when the price of the *option* drops $2 from it's highest sellable value, which is currently $3.95. That would mean that you sell it for $1.95 per share, or $195 less commissions, so roughly $194.33.  Since it's a put, that's only going to happen if the stock price *rises*, which is the opposite of what you predict.

There's not a way on eTrade to trigger the sale of an option when the *underlying* drops by an amount. Since you want to cash in a put if the stock goes down (which would *raise* the price of the option), what you want is a *limit* order instead of a *stop* order.

So you could, for example, set a limit order of $5.95 which is $2 *more* than the current sellable price, or roughly $595 less commissions.

Or, since there's only 10 days until expiry and a drop will make the option more in-the-money and closer to its intrinsic value, just hold the option until maturity. At worst you'll sell your shares for $160, or keep them if they're worth more than that.